# Does the order of query string parameters affect cached objects?

Tags: browser, caching, query-string

Consider a request for...

```
http://www.foo.com/bar?x=1&y=2
```

... and a subsequent request for...

```
http://www.foo.com/bar?y=2&x=1
```

Will a web browser consider them the same for caching purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep a browser never keeps track of the order of get parameters to handle cache

Comment: This answer, however correct, could really benefit from some detail - ideally some reference to modern browsers.

Comment: I can't find anything on the internet backing up your claim. What browsers did you confirm this with?